# Does CREATE DATABASE overwrite?

Tags: sql, database, ddl, ansi-sql

I am writing a simple SQL script and need to create a new database if it doesn't exist, or leave the database alone if it does already exist (and not overwrite it or drop-n-swap its tables).

I need this to be ANSI-compliant; according to [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_db.asp):

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
```

...is ANSI-compliant. But nowhere does it state what its behavior is if `my_db` already exists.

So I ask: how do I write ANSI-compliant SQL that creates `my_db` if it doesn't exist, or that doesn't do anything to it if it already does exist? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you're using is *specified per vendor*, and the specification (at [least SQL:2008](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql200n.zip) (12.1MB zip archive)) does not mention what the implementation is for the creation of a database, leaving the details up to the individual vendor.

Its possible to have a RDBMS that could overwrite when issued a `CREATE DATABASE` but in my personal experience unlikely. Your best option here is to test with each RDBMS vendor's product you intend to support.

Comment: Thanks @cfeduke (+1) - please see my comment under Matt McHugh's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: Because `CREATE DATABASE` is not ANSI compliant there's not going to be a standards compliant way to handle errors returned by the execution of the statement (imagine if there was an edge case where it replaced the database and no error was raised). There's no simple solution here unfortunately; the best you can do is pick the main database vendors you want to support and create a script that drives the correct SQL command to the RDBMS, and leave unsupported RDBMS as user beware.

Comment: Thanks @cfeduke (+1 again) - last followup, I promise: when you say "*...the best you can do is pick the main database vendors you want to support and create a script that drives the correct SQL command to the RDBMS...*" - can you give me an example of how to do this? Pick your favorite RDBMS; I just want to see an example of how you "auto-detect" the vendor, and then run `CREATE DATABASE` specific to that vendor. Thanks again!

Comment: One way of differentiating I've seen used in the past was to have a shell script look for open ports on the database server. Admittedly this approach is a little dated but it will likely work for many cases. If that fails, or the port detected doesn't reply to a connection request with the expected DB driver (don't just assume that 5432 is PGSQL for example, someone could have put Oracle there) then checking common install paths is another option. Ultimately prompting the end user should cover most edge cases with the exception of PEBKAC.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to create a database that already exists, your DBMS will throw an error.  The process for determining if a DB exists and then creating if it doesn't varies by DBMS.  In any case, it will not drop and recreate the DB.

Comment: Thanks @Matt McHugh (+1) - is there an ANSI-compliant method to "catch" the raised error (thrown when attempting to create an existing DB) and handle it? That might be a viable solution for me...thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of one.  All of the error handling techniques I know are vendor-specific.

Comment: Thanks Matt McHugh (+1 again) - please see my last followup to cfeduke's answer - I have the same question for you!